# How to keep website running if cache server(redis) failed

Tags: cakephp, caching, redis

I have a cakephp app.And using  Redis  for managing cache.
In `config->bootstrap.php` I use

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'Redis'))
```

If Redis goes down, my site is down.I want to keep alive my site if redis down.
what kind of configure i need to do.

Should I use a try catch in `bootstrap.php`? Like setting  `engine=>File`, if redis not found ??

But File cache is very slow.

Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Redis doesn't normally crash - so if it's crashing there's a real problem to fix. You could try/catch and use a backup cache store - I would suggest to use [the null engine](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Cache/Engine/NullEngine.php) because the amount of time redis is offline should be 1) very little 2) painfully obvious to you that you need to do something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that: **Don't let Redis crash** and figure out *why* it keeps crashing. You want to work around the symptoms but not tackle the real problem. The real problem is the crashing Redis server, so fix that.

If you insist on keep working with an unstable system you already named your solution: Check if the Redis server is up and fall back to a second Redis server or another cache config in bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

If the Redis server crashes, have a mechanism to skip the Redis cache server.
Like,

```
if(redis.isDown()){
   //call db directly.
} else {
   //call redis server
}
```